# How to replace all square brackets in string using Java replaceAll(regex,replacement) method

Tags: java, regex

I am learning java and I want to replace all `[] and {}` with a space   using java `RegExp`.

What i'm tried,

```
final String data = "{a:b,c:d,e:[f,g,h]}";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("[{}[]]", " "));
```

but am getting `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 5 [{}[]].
     ^`

I think the java thinks that the `]` at 5th position as the ending point of the `RegExp`.

**So how can i escape that square bracket and replace all `[]{}` with a space  .**

Comment: For your reference, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 5):

You must escape `[`, `]` present  inside `[]` (character class)

```
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("[{}\\[\\]]", " "));
```

Comment: So the double slash is used to escape syntax char in regex ? or it can be used with any string? i think commonly we use `\` single slash to escape a char from a string. isn't ?

Comment: Ya, I other lang which use `/` as delimiter uses only single slash. But in case of `"` , you need to escape backslash one more time. Or otherwise it would be readed as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special characters `[` and `]` with backslashes:

```
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("[{}\\[\\]]", " "));
```